# riscv objdump how to set to print x0-x31 register names instead of abi names

Tags: assembly, disassembly, cpu-registers, riscv, objdump

I am trying to disassemble a risc-v binary using riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump, and i want to get register names as seen in hardware (like x0-x31), and not like in the abi (sp, s0, a..).

The objdump manual doesn't seem to have such an option for RISC-V. In fact, the manual doesnt seem to have any info relating to RISC-V.
There is -M reg-names-raw for ARM, does anyone know if such a flag is available?

`riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -M"no-aliases" -M"gpr-names-raw" -d hello`
-> returns
0:  riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump: unrecognized disassembler option: gpr-names-raw
neither gpr-names-raw or reg-names=ARCH are recognized options

I want something like this:

```
addi    x1,x1,-32
sw      x2,28(x3)
addi    x5,x5,32
```

instead of this

```
addi    sp,sp,-32
sw      s0,28(sp)
addi    s0,sp,32
```

Comment: `-Mnumeric` should work, according to binutils source code. Also `objdump --help` should have printed _"numeric       Print numeric register names, rather than ABI names."_

Comment: @jester Thank you! That is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 5):

> The following RISC-V-specific disassembler options are supported for use
>   with the -M switch (multiple options should be separated by commas):
>
> ```
> numeric       Print numeric register names, rather than ABI names.
>
> no-aliases    Disassemble only into canonical instructions, rather
>               than into pseudoinstructions.
> ```

(GNU objdump 2.33.1 `--help`)

Example call:

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d num.o -M numeric

num.o:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   fe010113            addi    x2,x2,-32
   4:   00812e23            sw  x8,28(x2)
   8:   02010413            addi    x8,x2,32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--- binutils-patch/opcodes/riscv-dis.c
+++ binutils-patch/opcodes/riscv-dis.c
@@ -47,8 +47,8 @@
 static void
 set_default_riscv_dis_options (void)
 {
-  riscv_gpr_names = riscv_gpr_names_abi;
-  riscv_fpr_names = riscv_fpr_names_abi;
+  riscv_gpr_names = riscv_gpr_names_numeric;
+  riscv_fpr_names = riscv_fpr_names_numeric;
   no_aliases = 0;
 }
```